# I need to test my application's behavior while the oracle database is frozen. Therefore I need to simulate oracle DB freeze

Tags: linux, database, oracle

I tried this with kill -19 for oracle pmon process. But it didn't work for me. Please advise.
Oracle db is running on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to "simulate" that:

- Put your database in archivelog mode and fill all the space where the
  archivelog are located.
- Fill completely the space allocated in your    application tablespace
  (you will need to try to write data in there)

Comment: I have froze the data base by kill -19 to ora_lgwr process. (oracle log writer) . And then it doesn't allow to commit once we insert or update any table.

Comment: Good to know, Thanks for sharing